Does the US Federal Government have a way to control the number of housing permits issued nationwide for new homes?
Does the federal government in the US have a way to control the number of housing permits issued nationwide for new homes? Or is this something that is controlled only by local jurisdictions?


Does the federal government in the US have a way to control the number
of housing permits issued nationwide for new homes?

No. It can create tax and housing grant incentives to build new homes, but it cannot control this directly.

Or is this something that is controlled only by local jurisdictions?

Land use regulation is predominantly a city and county function. But, in a handful of U.S. states, there is some state level land use regulation.

The department of housing and urban development (HUD) can greatly influence state and local zone laws by granting or withholding federal monies.
